# How to follow godoc links to structures in commentaries?

Tags: go

Something is wrong with my godoc installation and I'm unsure what.

What I am doing:
`godoc -http=:6060`

I want to browse stdlib documentation.

It is good until I click on links to struct in comments.

For instance in archive/tar, the `Reader` `Next` method has a link to `filepath.IsLocal`. When I try to follow that link I get the error:

```
lstat $GOROOT/path/filepath: no such file or directory
```

My environment variables are:

- **GOPATH**: `/Users/jon/go`
- **GOROOT**: `/usr/local/go`

What should I do to navigate the doc without this broken link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sat 22 Apr 2023 15:38:23 BST

There seems to be a problem with the `godoc` tool producing links for  "[selector expressions](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/master:godoc/linkify.go;drc=d5f48fca5379171ebce583082a3dd683c8f8ad75;l=145)" that refer to other packages.

A similar broken link can be found in the docs for `func (*Certificate) CheckSignatureFrom` referencing `Certificate.Verify` (at http://localhost:6060/pkg/crypto/x509/).

When a "broken" link is encountered (http://localhost:6060/path/filepath#IsLocal), prefix the URL.path with `pkg/` (http://localhost:6060/pkg/path/filepath#IsLocal).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using pkgsite since godoc seems to be deprecated.